# How to add Spinner to Toolbar Subtitle

Tags: android, spinner, toolbar, custom-adapter

I have implemented code to `add Spinner to Toolbar` using **custom Adapter** see this [post](http://android-pratap.blogspot.in/2015/01/spinner-in-toolbar-example-in-android.html)

[image]

But now I need to add same `spinner to Subtitle of Toolbar`, Here I need your help.... **could you please ?**

toolbar.xml -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
     >

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_nav"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

Comment: may I know the reason ?? DOWNVOTE

Comment: In posted image you have already added a Spinner to subtitle of Toolbar. then what is issue?

Comment: Answer is very simple take `LinearLayout`  insdie that put 2 spinners

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK I would like to show App Name in Title, but like to use spinner in place of Subtitle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="?attr/colorPrimaryDark"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
     >

   <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv_title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
   <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner_nav_sub"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```